# Java: how to account for (full) names of varying token length in an external file using a scanner

Tags: java, eclipse, file, java.util.scanner

Firstly, this is my first post here. I've done some searching but can't seem to find anything that is applicable. Please link if you know where I should look!

I've got a txt file formatted as below saved to my desktop:

```
    Isaac Newton 84 James
    Clark Maxwell 48 Marie Curie 66
    Aristotle 62
```

I'm wanting a scanner to run through the file breaking the data into `'name'` and `'age'`, resulting in `...println(name + " " + age)`. I tried this with two while loops as below and Eclipse doesn't return any errors, it just lags right up and outputs nothing.

Literally just after I wrote this, Eclipse crashed entirely saying it had a heap error and has run out of memory.

I've since realized that the `!scan.hasNextInt()` doesn't really make logical sense... if I called a String token as a `scan.nextInt()` value it would error, so I'm unsure why it didn't.

Ultimately, any ideas on how to do what I want using scanners or ideas as to why the below code killed Eclipse would be awesome.

```
String fileName = "C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\testing.txt";

File myFile = new File(fileName);

String name = "";
int age = 0;

Scanner scan = new Scanner(myFile);

while(scan.hasNext()){
    while(!scan.hasNextInt()){
        name = name + " " + scan.hasNext();         
        System.out.print(name + " ");
    }
    while(scan.hasNextInt()){
        age = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println(age);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just use one `while`, and use `if` to verify if is `int` for age or is not int, which will be the name:

```
   while (scan.hasNext()) {
        if (!scan.hasNextInt()) {
           name += scan.next() + " ";
        } else {
           System.out.print(name + " " + scan.nextInt() + " ");
           name = "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Legend - thank you. Had to change it to `.println` instead of `.print` to get them each on a new line, but that's perfect. Any ideas as to why the original was hated so much?

Comment: @JordanMacLachlan well, about heap memory issue, the reason is in `name = name + " " + scan.hasNext();` in the second `while`, you need to change `hasNext()` to `next()`. But even with this your logic is not right, try to debug and I'm sure you will findout

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the two inner while loops, they can be replaced with if statements

```
if(scan.hasNextInt()){
    age = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println(age);
 }
else{
    name = name + " " + scan.next();
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solves your problem. What I did is import the entire thing and then do the formatting in memory rather than doing it when reading the line (especially since the line doesn't contain all the data we need).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String fileName = "/path/to/file.txt";
    byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName));

    String fileContents = new String(encoded);

    String[] contents = fileContents.split("\\s");
    for (String element : contents) {

        if (!element.isEmpty()) {
            if (!isNumeric(element)) {
                System.out.printf(element + " ");
            } else {
                System.out.println(element);
            }
        }
    }
}

private static boolean isNumeric(String str) {

    try {
        double d = Double.parseDouble(str);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data file consists of pairs of

*name age*

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    String fileName = "test.txt";

    File myFile = new File(fileName);

    String name = "";
    int age = 0;


    Scanner scan = new Scanner(myFile);

    scan.useDelimiter(" ");

    while (scan.hasNext())
    {
        if (scan.hasNext())
        {
            name = scan.next();
            System.out.print(name + " ");
        }

        if (scan.hasNextInt())
        {
            age = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println(age);
        }
    }
    // TODO code application logic here
}
```